# What is the best choice to compare strings?

Tags: php

I have these two implementations here, which pick a text file from another website and compare these files to a local text file:

**Implementation 1:**

```
function compareHash($remote , $local){

    $str_remote = file_get_contents($remote);
    $str_local  = file_get_contents($local);

    $hash_remote = md5($str_remote);
    $hash_local  = md5($str_local);

    return $hash_remote === $hash_local;
}

$igual = compareHash('cache/text.txt' , 'http://php.net/text.txt');

if($igual)
    echo 'mesmo conteudo';
else
    echo 'lascou-se não é igual!'   ;
```

**Implementation 2**

```
$v_01 = file_get_contents('cache/text.txt');
$v_02 = file_get_contents('http://www.php.com/text.txt');

if(strcmp($v_01, $v_02) != 0) {
   echo 'differently strings';
} else {
   echo 'same strings';
}
```

In the first implementation , is it good to convert strings using MD5? Which is the best choice, and is the most efficient in terms of processing speed?

Comment: The answer lies within the question: How do you define "best"? Fastest - measure it! Easiest to read - read it! etc.

Comment: Well, do you care about accuracy? Hashes have collisions. Do you care if you say 2 colliding strings are the same string? If not, why not?

Comment: fastest and will do not have problems, I read a good while ago that md5 has problems during conversion correct?

Comment: The best way to compare strings is to simply compare them.  Why would taking a hash first be better?

Comment: so hash for you is the best choice? I preffer the code 2, and you?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your requirements.

You could just `$string_1 == $string_2` if you want a quick comparison that fails after the first difference. That will perform well enough.

If you're doing anything with cryptography, you should consider a constant-time string comparison function to make your code resistant to timing attacks.

https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode

If you're using PHP 5.6.x or newer, you want [`hash_equals()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php).